# CSS footer cannot adjust height

Tags: html, css, footer

I am trying to create a page and I want to adjust the height of the footer. But I failed.
The `div#F {background:yellow;height: 40px}` <--height is not working. Please help!

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div#C {margin:auto; width:1200px; height:830px} 
div#H {background:pink;}
div#Menu {background:pink;}
div#A {float: left; width:80%; background:red; height:700px} 
div#B {float: right; width: 20%; background:green;height:700px}
div#F {background:yellow;height: 40px}
</style>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="C">
<div id="H">
</div>
<div style="height: 35px;" id="Menu">Menu</div>
<div id="A">Left floating div</div>
<div id="B">Right floating div</div>
<div id="F">Footer</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add clear both at footer.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5gv43/)

```
   div#F {clear:both;background:yellow;height: 40px}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear your floated elements with:

```
div#F {
    background:yellow;
    height: 40px;
    clear:left;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/J9C9L/)**

Comment: Not `clear:left` it should be `clear:both` as elements are floating in both directions `left` and `right`

Comment: @A.K - No, clear left works perfectly fine as clearing the left forces the div below the floated element. Clear right and clear both also work, but there's nothing at all wrong with left.

Comment: I didn't tell that it is wrong I am telling you the proper techniques: [For your reference please](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear)

Comment: @A.K - What does your link to MDN's page on the clear property tell me? I'm pretty sure I have a decent grasp on the concept. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

change your css

```
div#F {background:yellow;height: 40px;float;left;width:100%;}
```